# Accessing Analysis Services from Windows 8 Metro Applications

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ssas, mdx

I have a series of large sql server analysis services cubes and I am wondering what the best approach is for talking to those cubes from devices like a Windows 8 tablet or a mobile device like Windows Phone 7.

My current thought is to leverage ASP.NET MVC 4 and the WebAPI feature to build a simple API, the web server gets the requests and then determines how to build up an MDX query, issues it via ADOMD and then parses the results, hydrates some model and sends it back down to the client as JSON or XML. This strikes me as quite a lot of work for something that is in effect, plumbing.

Does anyone know of a better solution? SQL 2012 is certainly an option if there is a better solution in the box with it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you reach any better solution ? .. cause i'm currently trying to do the same.